# How can we handle clicks between pages on tvOS TVML?

Tags: xcode, tvos

For those who started scratching beneath the surface, I am trying to embed a video using [tvOS TVML](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yIVkynrE-YU), I need to let the user go through the list of images then click on the image to go to another page (this could be doable in swift), but how can we bridge between pages inside TVML

PS: TvOS has been announced three days ago, in case you think it's a very vague question, you should know that there is no place other then SO to ask questions.

Comment: You could also ask on the official TVMLKit forum on Apple's website: https://forums.developer.apple.com/community/app-frameworks/tvmlkit

Answer (score 1):

To navigate to other pages, you need to push these pages on the stack:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var newPageDocument = parser.parseFromString(NEW_PAGE_XML, 'application/xml');
navigationDocument.pushDocument(newPageDocument);
```

To return to the previous page, you can press the Menu button on the remote or call the popDocument method of navigationDocument:

```
navigationDocumemt.popDocument();
```